# Angular Compiler was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Estrou trabalhando atualmente em um projeto, consumindo um api rest a partir do angular, porém ao decorrer, estou me deparando com erro que está me retornando que tenho 2 pacotes webpack dentro da minha aplicação.

Tentei achar alguma solução sobre o caso, porém nenhuma com sucesso. Já fiz de tudo, apago as pastas(nodes_modules e packaje-lock.json - conforme algumas situações parecida com a minha, porém não consigo achar de fato o que está causando isso) e instalo novamente com npm install, porém fica retornando o mesmo erro, segue abaixo os prints da tela do erro e do meu package.json.

A versão do angular/cli está a 6.0.8 conforme a listagem do 1º webpack, meu ts está na versão 2.7.2.

conforme mencionei apago os arquivos insta-los novamente conforme prints abaixo porém quando dou o ng serve novamente me retorna o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tenta rodar o npm installl com sudo

Comment: Já fiz isso tbm, porém continua o mesmo erro, obrigado!

Comment: Faz assim desinstala o node, limap o node_modules tanto global quanto do projeto, limpa o cache do npm  e instala novamente.

Comment: Sem sucesso ainda, dou o git clone no master do repositório do projeto, no gitgnore, já esta configurado para não subir os arquivos de dependências(node_modules), ou seja não vem nenhuma dependência instalada, quando executo o npm install me gera esse erro, não consigo achar essas dois webpack, fiz tudo conforme vc falou, apaguei o projeto, dei o git clone, apaguei o nodejs, limpei o cache do npm, e não estou conseguindo achar esse maldito erro.

Comment: obs: e quando eu dou o npm install chega um certo momento ele para de extrair os pacotes para instalar, só depois de dois ou três vezes que ele terminar a instalação do npm install com sucesso, de fato não sei o que está gerando esse erro.

Comment: obs 2: quando acabo de dar o npm install e dou um npm ls @ngtools/webpack, ele me lista novamente os dois webpack conforme mostrado na imagem a cima.